# How can I encrypt data with a public key in Node.js?

Tags: encryption, node.js, public-key-encryption

In *crypto*, I see only Signer/Verifier for doing digital signature and Cipher/Decipher with symmetric key encryption.

How do I encrypt data with public key?

Comment: Is "Signer", "Verifier", "Cipher", and "Decipher" literal?

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in the official nodejs api docs here:
[crypto.publicEncrypt(key, buffer)](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptopublicencryptkey-buffer)

> Encrypts the content of buffer with key and returns a new Buffer with encrypted content. The returned data can be decrypted using the corresponding private key, for example using crypto.privateDecrypt().
>
> If key is not a KeyObject, this function behaves as if key had been
> passed to crypto.createPublicKey(). If it is an object, the padding
> property can be passed. Otherwise, this function uses
> RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING.
>
> Because RSA public keys can be derived from private keys, a private
> key may be passed instead of a public key.

So the answer is:

```
var encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, buffer);
```

Comment: Is there a study correlating the compliance with the number of requests?

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in my [NaCl bindings](https://github.com/thejh/node-nacl). From its API:

```
// Encrypt and sign
box(message, nonce, pubkey, privkey)

// Decrypt and validate
unbox(box, nonce, pubkey, privkey)
// Generates a new keypair, returns {private: <buffer>, public: <buffer>}
boxKeypair()

// Lengths of nonces and public and private keys in bytes
// { nonce: x, pubkey: x, privkey: x }
lengths.box
```

Comment: Probably not useful any more: https://blog.chromium.org/2017/05/goodbye-pnacl-hello-webassembly.html

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach is using [Cryptographic Message Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) (CMS). It's not a pure Node.js solution, but you likely have all tools you need in the box. Below is the example using OpenSSL:

Generate x509 certificate (recipient) and private key files (in Bash):

```
openssl req  -nodes -new -x509  -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

Encrypt/Decrypt message from standard input (in Bash):

```
 echo 123 | openssl cms -encrypt -recip cert.pem | openssl cms -decrypt -inkey key.pem
```

You can use -in/-out parameters to work with files. Below is an example you can use for Node.js:

```
require('child_process').execSync("openssl cms -encrypt -in file.json -recip cert.pem -out file.json.cms")
```

On Linux you'll likely have OpenSSL installed already. You can get OpenSSL  on Windows by installing [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), although you can also use built-in PowerShell commands. You'll need to generate a [PFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) certificate (using *New-SelfSignedCertificate*) or install existing one (can be generated with OpenSSL too). Once the certificate installed in the certificate store, you can use below commands for encryption/decryption:

```bsh
Protect-CmsMessage -to CN=MyCertName -Path file.json -OutFile file.json.cms
Unprotect-CmsMessage -Path file.json # It will find proper cert in cert store for you
```

Below is an example how to generate .pem and PFX certificates from the same private key using OpenSSL, and make messages interchangeable between OpenSSL and PowerShell.

Generate certificate with extensions (that's required on Windows):

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -subj '/CN=MyCertName' -addext extendedKeyUsage=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.80.1 -addext keyUsage=keyEncipherment
```

The above snippet will work only for newer versions of OpenSSL (1.1.1). Otherwise you need a separate file to define extensions. Then generate a PFX certificate (protect it with some password):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem -passout pass:P@ssw0rd
```

Then copy that PFX file to your Windows machine. You should be able to install it via PowerShell (*Import-PfxCertificate*) or manually (click on it and follow wizard, use all defaults). In order to make messages interchangeable use the `-inform \ -outform` parameter when using OpenSSL. For example:

```sh
openssl cms -encrypt -in file.json -recip cert.pem -outform PEM 
openssl cms -decrypt -in file.json.cms -inkey key.pem -inform PEM
# If having both OpenSSL/PowerShell on the same OS, use this for testing:
echo test | Protect-CmsMessage -to CN=MyCertName | openssl cms -decrypt -inform PEM -inkey key.pem
```

Btw, the CmsMessage commands will be available on [PowerShell Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_Core_6.0) 7.1, so you can use it on Linux/Mac too (it's in preview now, and a stable version will be released in Dec 2020).